Простыми словами, что это за параметры в ffmpeg?
-tile-columns 0 -threads 2

В доках непонятно, что за мозаики...
Кто нибудь может проще объяснить, и какое значение должно быть для различных качеств видео?
Как определяется какое значение должно быть для конкретного качества?
tile-columns и threads всегда указываются в паре?
Есть ли взаимосвязь между выше указанными параметрами и параметром -g 240?

Это только для vp9 видео.

Применяю кодек libvpx-vp9, хотелось бы разобраться в данных параметрах. Понимать что и как они делают

Если хотите разбираться, то вот https://forum.doom9.org/showthread.php?t=168947
